# imagemagick: делаю исходную картинку черно-белой, на выходе - она опять цветная

Tags: php, imagemagick

Делаю из цветного изображения черно-белое, потом его объединяю с другим черно-белым изображением и на выходе получаю опять цветное первоначальное изображение. Это глюк `imagemagick` или мой?

```
$image = new Imagick("t.jpg");
$image->setImageColorSpace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$line = new Imagick();
$line->newImage(300, 300, "#000000");

$image->compositeImage($line, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0); // bug? это строка возвращает цвет изображению
$image->writeImage("t1.jpg");
$image->destroy();
```

На картинке: 1 - исходное изображение, 2 - результат объединений, 3 - результат если закомментировать строку bug

[image: пример]

Comment: "This method should be used when creating new images. To change the colorspace of an existing image, you should use Imagick::transformImageColorspace()" - думаю, стоит последовать совету документации

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Правда, мне теперь интересно, почему с закомментированной bug-строчкой получается таки черно-белое изображение. Может, кто-то знает, как `setImageColorSpace` вообще работает?

Answer (score 0):

Как сказано в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php):

> Метод `Imagick::setImageColorspace` следует использовать при создании новых изображений. Чтобы изменить цветовое пространство уже существующего изображения, следует использовать [Imagick::transformImageColorspace](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.transformimagecolorspace.php)

```
$image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
```